PowerBI Embed refresh function is throwing an exception
We're using code based off a previously-working Microsoft-provided example. Here is some code that binds UI elements to some event handlers:
    document.getElementById('btnViewFullScreen')
        .addEventListener('click', () => { this.embeddedReport.fullscreen(); this.LogEvent("View Fullscreen", ""); });
    document.getElementById('btnPrint')
        .addEventListener('click', () => { this.embeddedReport.print(); this.LogEvent("Print", ""); });
    document.getElementById('btnRefresh')
        .addEventListener('click', () => { this.embeddedReport.refresh(); this.LogEvent("Refresh", ""); });
    document.getElementById('btnReset')
        .addEventListener('click', () => { this.embeddedReport.reload(); this.LogEvent("Reload", ""); });

Full screen, print, and reload work perfectly. Only refresh() is broken.
Here's the stack trace:
powerbi.js:9574 
 Uncaught (in promise) undefined
rejected    @   powerbi.js:9574
Promise.then        
step    @   powerbi.js:9575
(anonymous) @   powerbi.js:9576
__webpack_modules__../src/report.ts.__awaiter   @   powerbi.js:9572
__webpack_modules__../src/report.ts.Report.refresh  @   powerbi.js:10315
(anonymous) @   Embed.js:132

I can set breakpoints in the following:
    Report.prototype.refresh = function () {
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
        var response, response_15;
        return __generator(this, function (_a) {
            switch (_a.label) {
                case 0:
                    if ((0, util_1.isRDLEmbed)(this.config.embedUrl)) {
                        return [2 /*return*/, Promise.reject(errors_1.APINotSupportedForRDLError)];
                    }
                    _a.label = 1;
                case 1:
                    _a.trys.push([1, 3, , 4]);
                    return [4 /*yield*/, this.service.hpm.post('/report/refresh', null, { uid: this.config.uniqueId }, this.iframe.contentWindow)];
                case 2:
                    response = _a.sent();
                    return [2 /*return*/, response.body];
                case 3:
                    response_15 = _a.sent();
                    throw response_15.body;
                case 4: return [2 /*return*/];
            }
        });
    });
};

and what I see is a sequence of executions of that switch statement with values 0, then 1, then 2, then 3, and the requests in case 2 and 3 return with a 500 http status code. This is especially confusing to me as this is supposed to be calling the powerBI backend transparently - I'm just using the embed component and exposed API.
Any ideas on why I might be getting a 500 here? Seems like it must be built into the library, which is on the most recent version at 2.23.1.
